# Is a double elbow code-compliant for merging two residential drains?

Tags: plumbing, plumbing-fixture, pvc

[image: Double Elbow]

I'm working on a project where I have two fixtures coming in from the left and right, and then the waste water exits downwards vertically. My question: Is a 1-1/2" PVC double elbow for this up to code?

I notice that Home Depot doesn't really stock these, and I predict that some waste water would shoot into the opposite side before it all rinses downwards. But I can't see any other use for these besides what I'm doing, so they must be legal in some situation if they are available to order, right?

Comment: @isherwood I am planning to have vents within 3' of the fixtures. They are not set up yet. They will be pretty far away from this elbow in question.

Comment: @isherwood The vents will be in between the fixtures and their respective elbow entrance. They will run vertically. I do have the flexibility to change that as this point. I hope this is enough info to help; please let me know if you have any other questions.

Comment: Good info. Please include it in your question.

Comment: We have some skilled plumbers on board that should be able to give you a solid answer. They must be on vacation today. :)